# Factor analysis for categorical target variable

Tags: pca, categorical-data, dimensionality-reduction

I'm doing some research into factor analysis and I've hit that barrier where I don't know what search terms to use.

I'm trying to see if something is possible. Basically I have a data set with ~100 numerical variables. Each record also has a target variable which is a category. My ultimate goal is to perform knn on this data set. To reduce the dimensionality I ran PCA which gave a minor performance boost.

My understanding is that PCA reduces the data set to variables which capture the most variance in the multi-dimensional data set. But this method doesn't even consider the category that each record has.

Is there any method to reduce the number of dimensions, or identify key factors that specifically contribute to the target variable?

This may be poorly worded, so let me know if it doesn't make sense and I'll try to clear it up.

Thanks!

Comment: You have made an astute observation, one that often escapes otherwise very well-trained practitioners. The distinction you are looking for is between *supervised* and *unsupervised* learning. You have a supervised problem in that there is a response variable for each observation. PCA is nominally an unsupervised technique, though there are supervised versions of it. That said, they are usually geared towards regression problems, whereas yours appears to be classification. You might search for something like "supervised feature selection for classification" or similar. Cheers.

Comment: You might look at feature elimination via support vector machines.  An example can be found [here](http://www.stanford.edu/group/wonglab/RSVMpage/R-SVM.html).  The benefit of this method is that SVMs depend on class labels being assigned to data.  This technique can be adapted to the multiclass situation as well.

Comment: PCA does dimension reduction within a set of variables. To do dimension reduction that maximizes correlation *between* sets of variables, you may want to look at *[canonical correlation analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation)*. (In the case where you have a univariate $y$, finding the linear combination of $x$ that best predicts $y$ would basically just be regression, wouldn't it?)

Comment: Thanks for these, for some reason I hadn't considered this in terms of Supervised/Unsupervised learning. Got plenty to research now. Cheers!